# How do I import files in a webpack process from something like PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, webpack, webpack-file-loader

So **Webpack** is for bundling stuff. It has a lot of use case it seems, but I'm new to it so I might be missing something or using it incorrectly.

Currently it's probably mostly used for bundling JS and CSS and perhaps handling images with the *file-loader* or *url-loader*.

It also seems to bundle and do its plugin stuff in a cascading way. Meaning that a import in import will get evaluated and so I see that a image which is stored in a *CSS* file thusly:

```
background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
```

will go through the loader that handles *.jpg* files and gets moved through to the *dist* folder as well as the *CSS* will have the relevant path updated according to this. I'm not sure what part of **webpack** manages that, is it the *css-loader* perhaps that ensures this?

The problem arises since I'm currently developing a **WP** theme which uses *PHP* templates. This I never pass through the **Webpack** pipeline. *PHP* loader seems to be about converting to *HTML* and that is no good.

So if I have a `<img src="images/brand.jpg">` tag in the template I would have to manually import that image, and ensure that I have the right path to a currently non-existing bundle. I can also forget about inlining images using *url-loader* or *svg-loader* for example.

Is this just a ( currently ) non-existing use case for **Webpack** since most users are doing **React** or **Vue** projects with it.

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: So I've figured I could use html-loader, extract-loader, and file-loader if this was just basic HTML inside the php. Sadly the source is inside a PHP piece of code. Question if I need it or not since it is just `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '../images/brand.jpg'; ?>` and in theory Webpack should have the relativity figured out.

Answer (score 1):

If you still seek for an answer for that question - you can achieve that with Webpack manifest plugin (and [optionally] with Webpack copy plugin) and some php handler to parse the manifest.

I have a working version which you can see here
https://github.com/LowGravityPL/RaccoonWP/tree/master/public/core/themes/raccoon-twig

Webpack code is in `build-utils` directory